# Is "However so" an acceptable phrase?

Tags: phrase-usage

I had a question about the phrase "however so".  Make note that I am not talking about "... however, so ...".

For example, The sentence I want to write is:

> Bob told me that we can tweak the document however so.

The meaning I think/want "however so" to conveys here is: "Bob told me that we can adjust the document in any way we want".

I was wondering if anyone else had seen "however so" used in this way.  It seems familiar to me to use it, but something about the natural flow sounds extremely awkward to me, and I don't know why.

Has anyone encountered this usage before?

Thanks

Comment: It's not a common idiom but you read it in old texts with a British flavor.  Hard to say how to make it sound idiomatic to the "in tune" ear, unless you get advice from someone who's been raised with it.

Comment: I was raised with BrE but I've never seen or heard 'however so', and I'm like *old*. It doesn't sound idiomatic to me. When I was at school 'ever so', meaning 'very' or 'greatly', infuriated the English-teachers and was ever so popular. it could even go at the end of the sentence: 'It hurt ever so.' But not 'however so'. Could it be Irish?

Comment: Bob told me that we can however tweak the document so. "However so...' seems to be very rare. I haven't come across it.

Comment: It could be used in some kind of legal phaseology, e.g. “The presence of listed data on the owner’s computer shall be deemed an offence under the Act, *however so* it was received.”  From this, it might be possible to contrive some examples where people talking about a document use *however so* as a term to describe the style. It’s certainly not a common turn of phrase.

Comment: "Bob told me that we can tweak the document however **we want**."

Comment: "So" means *that way*, and "however so" means *that way to whatever degree*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an odd way to end a sentence. However so you choose to write it, I think it is unclear and therefore not the right place to use these words.

Note in the previous sentence I could drop the "so" with no change in meaning. The explicit "so" is not required in modern English.

For instance,
"Like to the rain" is an archaic way of saying "Like the rain." Although it's not required either way, the "to" is in modern English implied by "like." We do not say "the iPhone 6 is like to the 6XS but with a smaller screen."

Comment: But no-one says, "However so you choose to write it." You certainly **should** drop the *so* if you want it to make sense.

Comment: As I say, so did not change the meaning. It is implied by "however you." Paraphrase, "however you do." There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Ahh I see, so it sounds like "however so" was never a thing.  Thanks for all the help, I was about to use that phrase in an important document.